# RemotingException in IIS hosted Web App while running dll in separate app domain

Tags: c#, iis, remoting

I have a IIS hosted web app written in c#. On a service call it creates a new AppDomain and executes a dll after loading it. When the execution time exceeds 10 minutes I receive the Remoting exception below:

> System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Object
>   '/a3178091_1732_4272_b0bd_dae31e328450/lwntwiaw53jg1rd9gbvsigbe_25.rem'
>   has been disconnected or does not exist at the server.
>
> Server stack trace:
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelServices.CheckDisconnectedOrCreateWellKnownObject(IMessage
>   msg)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelServices.SyncDispatchMessage(IMessage
>   msg)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>
> at System.IO.Stream.set_Position(Int64 value)

The way I create the app domain is as below

```
    private AppDomain CreateDomainForTaskExecution(string baseDirectory)
    {
        AppDomainSetup domainSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
        domainSetup.ApplicationBase = baseDirectory;
        domainSetup.PrivateBinPath = baseDirectory;
        return AppDomain.CreateDomain("Domain for task execution", null, domainSetup);
    }
```

And then I invoke the remote object in the service call.

```
   newDomain = CreateDomainForTaskExecution(domainBaseDir);


            IExecutableTaskFactory taskLocator = (IExecutableTaskFactory)newDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(taskAssemblyFile.FullName, this.ExecutableTaskFactoryFullName);
            IExecutableTask executableTask = taskLocator.Create();
    IList<uint> ouputArguments = executableTask.OutputArgumentNames;

        IDictionary<uint, Stream> taskOutput = new Dictionary<uint, Stream>();
        foreach (uint argument in ouputArguments)
        {
            MarshalByRefObject stream = new MemoryStream();
            taskOutput[argument] = stream as Stream;
            ILease lease = (ILease)stream.InitializeLifetimeService();
            if (lease.CurrentState == LeaseState.Initial)
            {
                lease.InitialLeaseTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
                //lease.SponsorshipTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                //lease.RenewOnCallTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            }
            lease.Register(this);
        }

        // Register as a sponsor.
        foreach (Stream stream in inputArguments.Values)
        {
            ILease lease = (ILease)stream.InitializeLifetimeService();
            if (lease.CurrentState == LeaseState.Initial)
            {
                lease.InitialLeaseTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
                //lease.SponsorshipTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                //lease.RenewOnCallTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            }
            lease.Register(this);
        }

        executableTask.Execute(inputArguments, taskOutput);
        return taskOutput;
```

The taskLocator is a MarshalByRefObject and overrides the InitializeLifetimeService() function as follows:

```
    public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
    {
        ILease lease = (ILease)base.InitializeLifetimeService();
        if (lease.CurrentState == LeaseState.Initial)
        {
            lease.InitialLeaseTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
            //lease.SponsorshipTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            //lease.RenewOnCallTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        }
        return lease;
    }
```

The executableTask is also a MarshalByRefObject and similarly tries to get an unlimited Lease as above.

I have also tried to make my service object to be a ISponsor and in Renew I do

```
    public TimeSpan Renewal(ILease lease)
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    }
```

But Renewal is never called. I have looked up all links on Google and stack overflow but could not find a solution. What could be the possible problem?

Comment: I have also used the ITrackingHandler interface to find out that a MemoryStream object is getting disconnected. I have used the following code `// Called when the tracked object is disconnected.
        [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermissionAttribute(
         System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.LinkDemand,
         Flags = System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermissionFlag.Infrastructure)]
        public void DisconnectedObject(Object obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Tracking: An instance of {0} was disconnected.",
                obj.ToString());
        }`

Comment: At last found the solution, the streams in the inputargs and taskoutput were leased properly but the dictionary they were part of was not. So created a type that encapsulated the dictionary and had the IDictionary interface and also was a MarshalByRefObject with infine lifetime. This fixed the disconnected object errors from the remoting layer.